# Setting different colors to bars in MPAndroidChart Bar Chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

How do I set colors for different bars depending upon the value of Y-Axis? 
I am using the MPAndroidChart library to make the graphs. This is what I have done to make the bar chart:

```
        BarChart barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "Calorie Level");


        ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        labels.add("0");
        labels.add("1");
        labels.add("2");  

        BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
        barChart.setData(data);
        barChart.animateY(2000);
```

I am calculating the values from the following function. I need to set the color of each bars depending on the value of 'delta' given below

```
private void addCalories(int calories, int time)
        {   totalCals += calories;
            float HBNow = HBE * time / 24;
            float delta = totalCals - HBNow;
            entries.add(new BarEntry(delta, time));
            Log.e("My Activity:", "Delta" + delta + "Time:" + time);
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

you can create an arraylist containing your colors

```
ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

colors.add(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.dodger_blue));
colors.add(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.peach));
colors.add(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.medium_pink_three));
colors.add(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.aqua));
colors.add(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.greeny_blue));
colors.add(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.charcoal));
colors.add(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.charcoal_grey));
```

then set this array to your chart dataset like this

```
dataset.setColors(colors);
```

In your addCalories() function you can use your own logic to create this array containing your colors. Once you have calculated all the values you can set the color to your dataset.

Comment: Using ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.x) was key for taking the actual colors. When adding R.color.x only (without ContextCompat) the bars were being drawn with only the first color in the array, and with a high alpha (opacity). Is there an explanation?

Comment: @galaxigirl I have problem even with the  ContextCompat.getColor, it's always just first added color.

Answer (score 0):

try this use `barDataSet.setColor(Color.BLUE);` method to set color of  bars

```
 ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<>();
 BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(8f, 0); // Jan
 valueSet1.add(v1e1);

 BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Views");
 barDataSet1.setColor(Color.BLUE);

 ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets  = new ArrayList<>();
 dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
```

Comment: this will apply colour to single bar only.

Comment: @MohammedFarhan yes he need to set color in his dataSets the above ans is just hint

Answer (score 0):

This helped me a to get custom color to required column or piece. Make sure to add colors in same order in which your data is added so you get required color at required spot.

```
    colors.add(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.active));
    colors.add(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.recovered));
    colors.add(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.death));
    dataSet.setColors(colors);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "Calorie Level");
dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS);
```

Comment: This is largely the same as [@AskNilesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46947388/3025856) from four years ago, but with less detail. What's the benefit of using `ColorTemplate` over `Colors`? At least explain that.